# How to check all checkboxes in current form with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, checkbox

Consider this simple example code:

```
<form name="text" id="frm1" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1000"> Chk1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1001"> Chk2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1002"> Chk3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1003"> Chk4<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Select All<br>  
</form>

<form name="text" id="frm2" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4000"> Chk1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4001"> Chk2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4002"> Chk3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4003"> Chk4<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Select All<br>
```

I'm trying to get Select All to work in each form (forms are dynamically generated in my production code and have different, varying names)

I'm using this jquery but select_all only works for only the first form; it has not affect on forms below the first.

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
  } else {
      checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
  }
});
```

I can't figure out how to Check All checkboxes in any :checkbox contained within the form ID.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: Shameless plug: check out my [jQuery CheckAll plugin](https://github.com/mjball/jQuery-CheckAll) (still working on documentation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the same ID, which is invalid HTML and is causing the problem you're seeing. Change `id="select_all"` to `class="select_all"`, and `$('#select_all')` to `$('.select_all')`, and you should be good.

Comment: If only I could reclaim the last hour and a half of google search.

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with id `select_all`; that's not allowed. Change that to a class and try this:

```
$('.select_all').change(function() {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
  checkboxes.attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: No need to use `.is(':checked')` because you can just inspect the `.checked` property of the checkbox. No point having an extra jQuery call

Comment: Eh, jQuery's cheap. It's unlikely that's going to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique. You have two. If you want multiple elements, use `class="select_all"` and `$('.select_all')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_all').click(function() {
    $("input:checkbox", $(this).closest('form')).attr("checked", this.checked)
});
```

However, you will need only one item with id `select_all` for this to work. If you can change to a class of `select_all` then just replace the `#` with a `.` and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#select_all").click(function()               
        {
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            $("input[@name=name]").each(function()
            {
                this.checked = checked_status;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Also make sure you have one "select_all" class instead of two IDs.

Comment: This will not help. The problem is the duplicated ID. And then it will select *all* checkboxes of *all* forms.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after posting the code. Please view the first answer, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can not have two items with the same ID. 
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/t8a6d/)

html:

```
<form name="text" id="frm1" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1000"> Chk1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1001"> Chk2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1002"> Chk3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="1003"> Chk4<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="select_all_1"/> Select All<br>  
</form>

<form name="text" id="frm2" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4000"> Chk1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4001"> Chk2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4002"> Chk3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="4003"> Chk4<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="select_all_2"/> Select All<br>  
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    $('#select_all_1, #select_all_2').bind('click', function(event) {

        var 
            ref = this,
            refChecked = this.checked;

        $(this.form).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el) {
            if(this != ref)
              this.checked = refChecked;
        });

    });

});
```